# How to fix __exposedProps__ error on Greasemonkey (GM_xmlhttpRequest)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

I have written my first script for Greasemonkey, it is working great, except that it is returning **exposedProps** error in each page it is working on. I already fixed all other errors but this one is still there and based on some articles on web (like [this](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/08/22/mozilla-firefox-17-better-add-on-security-but-some-add-ons-may-break/)) it will break my script in the future when Firefox 17 is published. (Right now I'm using Firefox 15.0 and fortunately it just returns a warning error!)

I'm using GM_xmlhttpRequest in my script:

```
function doProcess(id, in_process_type){

    var set_id = GM_getValue("pid"+id);

    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://website_address/return_params.php",
        data: "pid="+set_id,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        onload: function(response) {
    --->    var params = response.responseText;
            params = params.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s)/gm,"");

            ..........
        }
    });
}
```

and this is error message that refers to the line that I put an arrowhead in front of it:

```
Error: Exposing chrome JS objects to content without __exposedProps__ is insecure and deprecated. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPConnect_wrappers for more information.
Source File: file:///Users/Mona/Library/Application%20Support/Firefox/Profiles/tonfd656.default/gm_scripts/MonaTest/MonaTest.user.js
Line: 133
```

I found this [page](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/08/20/exposing-objects-to-content-safely/), that offers a solution to this error, but honestly I can't figure out how I can use it here!

I really appreciate all your help in advance... 
And thanks for your time!

Comment: What Greasemonkey version are you using?  Are you injecting any code or creating `<script>` nodes?

Comment: @BrockAdams I have Greasemonkey Version 1.0 installed on my ff, I think it is the latest version, isn't it?!

Comment: I also included a remote JS file via direct code injection, but this function doesn't do anything with that script...

Comment: Yes, 1.0 is the latest GM release.  I asked that before realizing that this problem likely affects all current Greasemonkey versions, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem / potential-bug within Greasemonkey itself.  See:

- [*Issue #1595*, "Use **exposedProps**"](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1595)
- [*Issue #1607*, "GM_xmlhttpRequest response.responseText is undefined in Nightly17.0a1..."](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1607)

You might want to weigh-in and track those bug reports.

If you link to your **complete script**, we might be able to help with a workaround but, most likely, it can only be fixed within Greasemonkey itself.

Comment: I tried "use an explicit function", and it didn't work. so I guess we wait for Greasemonkey's fix.

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks for the links, I added them to my watch list... I tried your solution too, and it returned same error in function processResponse... I guess I wait for gm fix too... anyway thanks for your time! (The only reason I didn't accept your answer is because of the code that can't fix the issue, but if you remove that part I will accept it, because of the links and the point that it is a GM issue...)

Comment: Okay, I removed the suggested experiment since that's 2 reports that it didn't work. ... Note that you could/can edit the answer (or most anything) yourself.  It goes into a suggested-edit queue, but most all SE's are approved unless they're really bad.